# More information about Git cherry

Tags: git

I am working with Git and could not find more information about "Git cherry" than the documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry). I could not really understand the purpose of the "+" and "-" and can not fine additional information.

> Outputs the SHA1 of every commit in limit..head, prefixed with - for commits that have an equivalent in , and + for commits that do not.

Comment: Commits with a `+` are unknown to the remote version of the branch. Those with `-` are unknown too, *but* they have a (cherry-picked) commit with another hash and same changes. Commits already on the remote branch just aren't listed. What's the unclear part to you, so answerers can put emphasis on it?

Comment: So if I understood that right, I can track which commits are "cherry-picked" with the "-"?

Comment: Yes, that's the gist of it.